# Disable some Gmail shortcut keys

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Love Gmail shortcut keys but not all of them.  Is it possible to selectively delete some keys?

I tried going to `Settings` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` and clearing some of the defaults in the Key(s) column but doing just that doesn't allow me to save my changes.  The Save Change button is not active.  I can make the Save Change button active my adding a new key but when I save changes my deleted keys are brought back (and found I was able to define the same key to > 1 command, btw).  Any ideas?

Comment: "clearing some of the defaults in the Key(s)" - This presumably requires that the "Custom keyboard shortcuts" lab extension is enabled? Stock Gmail has no such option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, looks like it's all-or-nothing for Gmail shortcut keys.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to [Labs](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/labs) and enable the Custom Keyboard Shortcut lab experiment, you can set custom keyboard shortcuts for every available action. While this does not allow you to un-set a particular shortcut, you can use up to 3 keystrokes to define a shortcut. If you set a shortcut to something that you are highly unlikely to type, then it will be difficult to accidentally trigger it, effectively rendering it disabled.

FWIW, I found that I had to refresh the page to remove the old shortcut (bizarrely, the new shortcut works immediately).

Comment: +1. Damn, looks like there is no shortcut to 'Send mail' in that labs gadget. Just the shortcut I wanted to disable (Ctrl+enter)